# I didn't understand the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

"The mob was reportedly incensed after another car driven by a Sudanese youth ran over and killed a 35-year-old local".What does this sentence means?Here what the author wants to convey us?

Comment: Is it the word *incensed* or the structure of the sentence that confuses you? If it's because of the word *incensed*, then a dictionary would solve your problem. If it's because the structure, perhaps it's better to tell us more about the part that you understand (or the part you don't understand), so that others can address your problem more appropriately.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Yes, incensed means to become more anger but here in the sentence "another car driven by sundanese youth ran over and killed a 35-year-old local" .Does this line mean the car ran over the mob thats why they got more angry.

Comment: No, **another car ran over a local**.  "A local" means "a person living in that area".  If the car had run over the mob, it would say, "the car ran over the mob" or "ran over them".

Comment: The mob presumably *formed* because they were made angry by someone having been killed by a car.  They then assaulted the Tanzanian woman because they falsely associated her with the driver who killed their friend or neighbor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sentence:

> The mob was reportedly incensed after another car driven by a Sudanese youth ran over and killed a 35-year-old local.

*after* is a conjunction, and we have two clauses:

> 1) The mob was reportedly incensed
>   2) another car driven by a Sudanese youth ran over and killed a 35-year-old local

The sentence says that 2) happened first. The word *another* suggests that this car is not the only car in the news. According to the sentence, a car ran over and killed a local, and this car was driven by a Sudanese youth.

The sentence states that: 1) happened after 2).

As to *Does the sentence mean that the car ran over the mob?*, the answer is no. But the way it's written doesn't rule out the possibility that the 35-year-old local was in the mob, even though that would be unlikely, and the sentence doesn't seem to try to suggest that the 35-year-old local was in the mob.

Comment: The word *another* might also suggest simply that this is an additional car in the story.  In fact, if you look at the [article](http://www.dnaindia.com/india/report-bengaluru-tanzanian-girl-stripped-paraded-naked-2173497) from which the sentence was taken, it appears that there was only one incident; the first car in the story is the Tanzanian woman's car, from which she was removed during the assault.

Comment: @phoog Thanks! I agree that it's two cars rather than two car incidents in the news. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> The mob was reportedly incensed after another car driven by a Sudanese youth ran over and killed a 35-year-old local

The phrases "the mob was reportedly incensed" and "another car driven by a Sudanese youth ran over and killed a 35-year-old local" are separate.

The car "driven by a Sudanese youth" is what ran over and killed a 35-year-old local.  The sentence doesn't say whether that 35-year-old local was part of the mob or not, or why that would incense the mob.